P=NP iff for any two non-trivial languages A, B in coNP, A≤pB and B≤pA
Prove: $\text{P} = \text{NP}$ iff for any two non-trivial languages $A$ and $B$ in $\text{coNP}$, it holds that $A \leq_p B$ and $B \leq_p A$.
The part of assuming the reductions and proving $\text{P}=\text{NP}$ was fine, but I can't prove the second part without assuming that $\overline{A}$ is an $\text{NP- complete}$ language (thus $A$ is $\text{coNP- complete}$), and $B$ is in $\text{P}$ for the reductions.
I think there's a much easier (and correct) way that I don't see to prove the second direction.

If $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, then $\text{P} = \text{NP} = \text{coNP}$. Indeed, for every language $K\in \text{coNP}$, we have that $\overline{K} \in \text{NP} = \text{P}$, and as $\text{P}$ is closed under complementation, then $K\in \text{P}$ as well. Therefore, $\text{coNP} \subseteq \text{P}$.
Now it is sufficient to show that for all non-trivial languages $A$ and $B$ in $\text{P}$, there is a polynomial time reduction from $A$ to $B$. This is easy as a reduction, given input $x$, checks first whether $x\in A$ (this can be done in polynomial time as $A\in \text{P}$), and outputs $x_{in}$ if $x\in A$, and outputs $x_{out}$ otherwise, where $x_{in}$ and $x_{out}$ are words in and out of $B$, respectively. Note that the latter words exist as $B$ is non-trivial.
Note: we actually proved that if $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, then every non-trivial language in $\text{P}$ is $\text{NP-complete}$.
